# Simple array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array structure;

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
        [product_name] => Silver
    )

[1] => Array(
        [product_name] => Gold
    )

[2] => Array(
        [product_name] => Ride
    )

[3] => Array(
        [product_name] => Bronze
    )
)
```

I need it to be like this, but I can't figure out how. I can't implement an additional function, it needs to be clean and neat.

```
Array(
    [0] => Silver
    [1] => Gold
    [2] => Ride
    [3] => Bronze
)
```

Thanks for any help offered. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this works:

```
iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)), false);
```

Comment: Thanks alix. I've no idea what this is doing, but the code I'm working in is very OOP, so this seems more in keeping with that style. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array as &$value)
{
    $value = $value['product_name'];
}
```

Comment: Your solution is probably the simplest. But I suggest `unset $value;` afterwards to avoid problems if you reuse the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use array_map personnaly !

```
$array = array_map(function($product){return $product['product_name'];}, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($firstarray as $var) {
   $secondarray[] = $var["product_name"];
}
```

Comment: Can't you just drop the `$i` and use `$secondarray[] = $var["product_name"];`?

Answer (score 1):

If [product_name] is the key name, then this would work:

```
foreach($array as $i=>$a)
    $array[$i] = $a['product_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array("product_name" => "Silver"),
    array("product_name" => "Gold"),
    array("product_name" => "Ride"),
    array("product_name" => "Bronze")
);
```

You can do somenthing like this:

```
foreach($array as &$pos) $pos = $pos["product_name"];
```

So if you do a print_r($array) the result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Silver
    [1] => Gold
    [2] => Ride
    [3] => Bronze
)
```

Hope this help you.